Dictionary<Enum,decimal> for System.Text.Json deserialization error
I am unable to deserialize a Dictionary<Enum,decimal> from a JSON string when the enum key is in kebab-case-lower format. I tried defining JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.KebabCaseLower), but it is not working as expected. I'm using the C# 8 compiler in .NET 8
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{
            ""enum-one"": 1.1
        }";

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            Converters = { 
                new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.KebabCaseLower) 
            }
        };

        var enumOne = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestEnum>(@"""enum-one""", options); // This works

        var enumDictionary =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<TestEnum,decimal>>(json, options); // This will throw error
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    EnumOne = 1,
    EnumTwo = 2,
    EnumThree = 3
}


Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to TestEnum. Path: $.enum-one | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 23.

Code demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XA0uPX
Did I do anything wrong or missing something?

You have a misunderstanding of JsonNamingPolicy.KebabCaseLower -- this will successfully convert variations of 'Enum One' with a space to 'enum-one'  It will not successfully convert those values to match your 'EnumOne'  If your incoming data to be serialized/deserialized has hyphens, you'll need to write a custom converter to remove them

This question was incorrectly closed -- it contains a [mcve] in the question itself.

You have encountered a stated, intentional limitation of System.Text.Json by Microsoft.  From the docs:

Use a naming policy for dictionary keys
Naming policies for dictionary keys apply to serialization only. If you deserialize a dictionary, the keys will match the JSON file even if you set JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy to a non-default naming policy.

To confirm that this limitation holds even for Enum dictionary keys, you can check the reference source for EnumConverter<T> which includes the following comment:

// NB JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy is ignored on deserialization.
// This is true for all converters that implement dictionary key serialization.


So what are your options?
In .NET 7 and later Microsoft implemented support for naming policies when deserializing enum values (see issue #31619) so they clearly have the capability to deserialize an enum string taking the naming policy into account.  So you could create a JsonConverter decorator that forwards the call from ReadAsPropertyName() to Read():
public class DictionaryKeyJsonStringEnumConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    readonly JsonStringEnumConverter enumConverter;

    public DictionaryKeyJsonStringEnumConverter() : this(new JsonStringEnumConverter()) { }
    public DictionaryKeyJsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = default, bool allowIntegerValues = true) : this(new JsonStringEnumConverter(namingPolicy, allowIntegerValues)) { }
    public DictionaryKeyJsonStringEnumConverter(JsonStringEnumConverter enumConverter) => 
        this.enumConverter = enumConverter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumConverter));

    public sealed override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => enumConverter.CanConvert(objectType);

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        enumConverter.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options) is {} innerEnumConverter
        ? (JsonConverter?)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumConverterDecorator<>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert), new object? [] { options, innerEnumConverter })
        : null;
    
    class EnumConverterDecorator<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        readonly JsonConverter<TEnum> innerConverter;
    
        public EnumConverterDecorator(JsonSerializerOptions options, JsonConverter<TEnum> innerConverter) => this.innerConverter = innerConverter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerConverter));
        
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => innerConverter.CanConvert(typeToConvert);

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
            innerConverter.Write(writer, value, options);
            
        public override void WriteAsPropertyName(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            innerConverter.WriteAsPropertyName(writer, value, options);

        public override TEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            innerConverter.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);

        public override TEnum ReadAsPropertyName(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // If we simply call Read() here then System.Text.Json will intentionally choke because reader.TokenType is JsonTokenType.PropertyName not JsonTokenType.String
            // So we need to create a standalone JSON string literal, and read that.
            var quotedPropertyName = reader.GetQuotedUtf8PropertyName(stackalloc byte[64]);
            var valueReader = new Utf8JsonReader(quotedPropertyName, options.GetReaderOptions());
            return this.Read(ref valueReader.MoveToContentAndAssert(), typeToConvert, options);
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    internal static Span<byte> GetQuotedUtf8PropertyName(this ref readonly Utf8JsonReader reader, Span<byte> buffer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("Invalid TokenType {0}", reader.TokenType));
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> unquotedProperty = reader.HasValueSequence
            ? unquotedProperty = reader.ValueSequence.ToArray()
            : reader.ValueSpan;
        Span<byte> quotedProperty = unquotedProperty.Length + 2 <= buffer.Length 
            ?  buffer.Slice(0, 2 + unquotedProperty.Length) : new byte[2 + unquotedProperty.Length].AsSpan();
        quotedProperty[0] = (byte)'"';
        unquotedProperty.CopyTo(quotedProperty.Slice(1));
        quotedProperty[quotedProperty.Length - 1] = (byte)'"';
        return quotedProperty;
    }

    public static JsonReaderOptions GetReaderOptions(this JsonSerializerOptions? options) =>
        options is null ? new () : new ()
        {
            AllowTrailingCommas = options.AllowTrailingCommas,
            CommentHandling = options.ReadCommentHandling,
            MaxDepth = options.MaxDepth
        };      
    
    public static ref Utf8JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.None)
            return ref reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return ref reader;
    }
    
    public static ref Utf8JsonReader ReadAndAssert(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader) { if (!reader.Read()) { throw new JsonException(); } return ref reader; }
}

Then use it in place of JsonStringEnumConverter as follows:
var json = 
    """
    {
      "enum-one": 1.1,
      "3": 3.3
    }
    """;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Converters = { 
        new DictionaryKeyJsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.KebabCaseLower) 
    }
};
var enumDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<TestEnum,decimal>>(json, options);
var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(enumDictionary, options);

And your enum dictionary should round-trip successfully.
Notes:

In general it is not possible to apply naming policies when deserializing dictionary keys because JsonNamingPolicy does not have an UnconvertName(string) method that inverts ConvertName(string).  However, since enums have a fixed set of values, it is possible for the converter to build a back-mapping table -- which was in fact implemented in .NET 7.

Demo fiddle here.
In .NET 9 it may be possible to avoid the need for a custom converter by applying JsonStringEnumMemberNameAttribute directly to your enum values like so:
public enum TestEnum
{
    [JsonStringEnumMemberName("enum-one")]
    EnumOne = 1,
    [JsonStringEnumMemberName("enum-two")]
    EnumTwo = 2,
    [JsonStringEnumMemberName("enum-three")]
    EnumThree = 3
}

(I have not been able to test .NET 9 yet however.)
